# Copied DLL files are all zeros, but correct file size

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, backup, hardware-failure, dll

I used a program called SyncBackFree  (CNET 4.5 * rating) to copy a few thousand files from one hard-drive to another hard-drive.  All seemed to work okay, and there were no error, and no errors in the log file.  I just noticed a bunch of DLL files in one directory are the correct lengh, but the data is all zeroes (using a hex viewer).  I have randomly checked a few other files, such as images and videos, and they all seem okay.  Why are the dll files all zeroes?  I made the copy because my hard-drive is getting slow, and I was worried about possible failure.  I ran a program to test my system and hard-drive, and it says everthing is okay.

Comment: you might want to ask this question in the syncback support forum.

Comment: I googled syncback with this problem, and got zero matches, which I took to mean this program doesn't have any issue with DLL files.  Since you mentioned it, I have now posted the question on their forum, just in case.

Comment: i assume you've checked the original DLLs to make sure that they are not zeroed

Comment: you don't have a bad disk sector intersecting the files in that folder do you? `chkdsk /R`.

Comment: What do the original files look like using the same hex editor?

Comment: @jdigital - A moderator at the synback forum said he's never heard of this happening in any version of their backup software.

Comment: @Ramhound, (hex viewer) the originals - in the text area to the right there's a few characters and some dots, and then "This program cannot be run in DOS mode."

Comment: Use robocopy to see if same issue persists

Answer (score 1):

## Consider That The Originals May Have Been All Zeros

It simply may be a misconception. Please look at other dll's and see if has happened to all of them or has happened in some certain situations. dll's are simply files and so will be treated the same. also look to see if some restoration isn't still in progress or something weird like that because it may have put placeholder files that were all zeros of the right size and just was going to go back and fill it in with the proper data later. This may be a good possibility because i know that torrenting has an option you can set that does essentially the same thing so that it is guarenteed enough room to do it's thing.

Comment: That's not possible, as the program ran fine, but if I try to run the copy those zero'd dll files, the first dll read causes an error.

Comment: Also, viewing the original DLLs with a hew viewer shows they are not all zeros.

Answer (score 0):

This is more an observation than an answer, but it could be helpful so here goes...

I have a Win32 application that uses a dll [InPOut32.dll](http://www.highrez.co.uk/downloads/inpout32/) to access a parallel port directly while running under Windows 95 and XP.  This has  worked fine, even after the application was transferred to a 64-bit machine.
However, I tried to run it again the other day and got the message:

`inpout32.dll is either not designed to run on Windows or it contains an error. Try installing the program again using the original installation media or contact your system administrator or the software vendor for support.`

I opened the DLL file with a hex editor and it was filled with zeroes!  I am 90% certain that this has just started appearing on our x64 machines - i.e. the DLL was not snagged on before.

Luckily, it was still under development so there is a replacement available.  Placing that in the same folder as the exe got me working again.

So I'm thinking that maybe windows performs some sort of sanity check on the DLL when it loads it, but scrubbing it to zeroes seems a bit excessive.